# redirection for gdb commands

Tags: gdb

How I can redirect output of this command :

(gdb) x /a $esp
0x22ff30:       0x403064 <__register_frame_info+4206692>

to make this:

(gdb) x /s 0x00403064
0x403064 <__register_frame_info+4206692>:        "\nPress key (q for exit) ?    "

(gdb)

I mean something like:
(x /a $esp) | (x /s)

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the output of a command in GDB is not possible, as far as I know.
There is another way to do this, though:
`x /s *(void**)$esp`.

This will examine the memory at the address stored at the top of the stack.